# Como muestro todos los valores con check en un input checkbox inmediatamente despues de seleccionarlos, mostrarlos en un textarea

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Python/Django de BackEnd y HTML,CSS y Javascript de FrontEnd, en esta template tengo un formulario el cual contiene unos input de tipo checkbox con sus respectivos labels, Django automaticamente renderiza el formulario, el value que tiene cada uno de los checkbox es numerico, por lo mismo tanto ocupo agregar al textarea el valor que tiene el label para cada checkbox , debajo de estos inputs se encuentra un textarea en el cual me gustaria mostrar el valor del label para cada input inmediatamente despues de ser seleccionados. Les dejo mi intento en Javascript.

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load static%}
{%block title%}Consult{%endblock%}
{%block return%}<a href="{%url 'appointments:consults'%}"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></i></a>{%endblock%}
{%block body_block%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'appointments/css/update_consult.css'%}">
<h1 id="heading">Consult</h1>
<h4>Patient: {{consult.patient.first_names}} {{consult.patient.last_names}} <a href="{%url 'appointments:consults_list' consult.patient.pk%}"><i class="fas fa-book-medical"></i></a></h4>
<h4>Date: {{consult.datetime|date}}</h4>
<h4>Time: {{consult.datetime|time}}</h4>
<h4>Motive: {{consult.motive}}</h4>
<h4>Suffering: {{consult.suffering}}</h4>
<form method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <hr>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h2>General Info</h2>
            <h3>Vital Signs</h3>
            <p>{{consult_form.blood_pressure.label}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.blood_pressure}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.temperature.label}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.temperature}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.weight.label}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.weight}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.size.label}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.size}}</p>
            <h3>Exams</h3>
            <label for="id_medical_exams" id="medical_exams">Provide Exams</label>
            <p>{{consult_form.medical_exams}}</p>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper-one">
            <h2>Examination</h2>
            <hr>
            <h3>Organ System</h3>
            <p>{{consult_form.digestive_system.label}} {{consult_form.digestive_system}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.endocrine_system.label}} {{consult_form.endocrine_system}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.renal_system.label}} {{consult_form.renal_system}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.lymphatic_system.label}} {{consult_form.lymphatic_system}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.respiratory_system.label}} {{consult_form.respiratory_system}}</p>
            <br>
            <h2>Physical Exploration</h2>
            <hr>
            <p>{{consult_form.head_exploration.label}} {{consult_form.head_exploration}}</p>
            <p>{{consult_form.thorax_exploration.label}} {{consult_form.thorax_exploration}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="diagnose">
        <h2>Diagnose</h2>
        <p>{{consult_form.cie_10_group.label}} {{consult_form.cie_10_group}}</p>
        <p>{{consult_form.cie_10_detail.label}} {{consult_form.cie_10_detail}}</p>
        <p>{{consult_form.diagnose.label}} {{consult_form.diagnose}}</p>
        <p>{{consult_form.procedure.label}} {{consult_form.procedure}}</p>
        <p>{{consult_form.analysis.label}} {{consult_form.analysis}}</p>
        <p>{{consult_form.notes.label}} {{consult_form.notes}}</p>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <h2>Treatment</h2>
        <div id="drugs">{{consult_form.drugs}}</div>
        <small>If the drug you are looking for is not here, create a new one below.</small>
        <p>{{consult_form.medicine.label}} {{consult_form.medicine}}</p><br><br>
        <p>{{consult_form.actions.label}} {{consult_form.actions}}</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
<script>
function checkbox(){

  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('drugs');
  var checkboxesChecked = [];
  // loop over them all
  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
     // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
     if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].id);
     }
  }
  document.getElementById("id_actions").value = document.getElementsByTagName('label[for='+checkboxesChecked[i]+']');
}
</script>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega un ejemplo de cómo aparecen los _checkboxes_ y sus etiquetas en HTML.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta con una imagen de como renderiza mi formulario Django! @Triby